# Can We Restrict Google Maps NearbySearch to Not Return Specific Type?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on some implementation of Google Maps, lately  I've been trying to find nearest POIs for a marker that I'm putting on the map. But what I want at this point is, I don't want `nearbysearch` to return values for POIs that has the type of `ATM` when I search for `Bank`.
This query is what I use to get results;

```
service.nearbySearch({
    location:marker.position,
    radius: 250,
    type: ['bank']
}, 
function(searchResults, status){
/* code goes here */
}
```

Is there any way to exclude a type from query?

Comment: What is wrong with this question for gods sake! Why negativess??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most voted feature requests for Places API that you can see in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822993

This feature request as you can see was filed back in 2013, but unfortunately Google didn't set high priority on this task. You can star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google. Hopefully one day they can implement this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its odd that we can't specify which types we don't want. And also is odd that nearbySearch returns unwanted data and we are actually billed for the data we don't want. I hope they change the way of their thinking. But then again, you don't get a company that is worth billions by thinking customers' financials.. Thanks again @xomena.